# What is the explanation of the following list comprehension?

Tags: python

```
input_shape = tuple([i for i in input_shape if i is not None])
```

I am new to python and don't understand what's happening there.
As I see it is possible to be some analog of `C`'s `int a = 5 > 2 ? val1 : val2;`, but I can't figure it out.

I tried to separate it on small parts to understand, but it still makes no sense for me.
Like that:

```
i // this is already wrong for being single
for i in input_shape //that's correct for cicle
    if i is not None //ugh... so, and what if?
```

Comment: Items that fail the test (that are `None` here) will be skipped by the loop.

Comment: i is not None add the item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there with your separation. The inner part (what if) is the expression you noted being wrong (`i`), it actually goes inside. And what it does with it is expressed by being inside brackets `[]`; it puts those things in a list. spectras' answer shows how this works using a variable to hold that list. The construct is called a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Comment: Thanks for explaining this. I read the docs and especially like the phrase `which is more concise and **readable**.` below such `list comprehension` example :D

Answer (score 3):

Items that fail the test (that are None here) will be skipped by the loop.

```
input_shape = tuple([i for i in input_shape if i is not None])

# Roughly equivalent to    

result = []
for i in input_shape:
    if i is not None:
        result.append(i)
input_shape = tuple(result)
```

Conceptually the same, except the list comprehension will be faster as the looping is done internally by the interpreter. Also, it will not leave a `result` variable around, obviously.

Comment: This is the most complete answer which actually explains how list comprehensions work and should be accepted.

Comment: @AhsanulHaque - for someone like me, who completely don't understand how it works, `Yann Vernier` answer were more useful, because it actually explained how to read such construction. He explained that I need to move first `i` under `if` condition in mind to understand all this. All other answers simply says what's the result will be, instead of explaining how to read it.

Answer (score 1):

the `i for i` part can be anything, `x for x`, `y for y`, or even `Kosmos for Kosmos`.

```
>>> input_shape = [1, 2, 3]
>>> input_shape = tuple([i for i in input_shape if i is not None])
>>> input_shape
(1, 2, 3)
```

Here you can see, it converted my list to a tuple by looping over each item.

Look into a thing called list comprehension, as I am having a tough time explaining it

Answer (score 1):

```
input_shape = [1,2,3,None,5,1]
print(input_shape)
input_shape = tuple([i for i in input_shape if i is not None])
print(input_shape)
```

o/p

```
[1, 2, 3, None, 5, 1]
(1, 2, 3, 5, 1)
```

as @spectras pointed, Items that fail the test (that are None here) will be skipped by the loop.

Answer (score 1):

The following is a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
[i for i in input_shape if i is not None]
```

It returns only elements that are not `None`

Then, you call `tuple()` to convert the resulted list to tuple.

You can achieve the same result by using an ordinary `for` loop like below:

```
input_shape = [1, 2, None, 'a', 'b', None]
result = []

for i in input_shape:
    if i is not None:
        result.append(i)

print(result)
# Output: [1, 2, 'a', 'b']
```

Now, we convert `result` (of type `list`) to `tuple` like this:

```
final_result = tuple(result)
print(final_result)
# Output: (1, 2, 'a', 'b')
```